# ImageViews change colors upon selection of one of their "brother" ImageViews

Tags: java, android

The issue that I am having is I have a `comment_item.xml` with the user's **comment, username, like and dislike and comment** `ImageView` and also a `TextView` for number of **comments, number of likes, and number of dislikes**. The problem is of a post has for example 13 comments and I like or dislike one of the comments by clicking on the `ImageView` the other ones "blink". What I mean by that is that in my Activity I made it so that when you hit like the thumb `ImageView` turns from grey to red, and if you hit dislike `ImageView` it turns from grey to black and then you get the updated number of likes or dislikes alongside. But when I hit the `ImageView` for like or dislike all the other comment's like and dislike `ImageViews` also turn a different color then come back to the color they were at originally... It's like a "blink" per say, so you guys understand what I mean by the action taking place.

How can I prevent that from happening. All the other comment's like and dislike `ImageView` shouldn't react if I hit like or dislike for some other comment...

I think the problem might be in my xml file, but I am not 100%. Uploaded a picture so you guys can see the UI. Now when I click on either like or dislike all the other likes and dislikes "blink" change to the opposite color they are in and then switch back... like a blink. I need that to not happen. They should not be reacting if I'm hitting like or dislike on another post...

[image]

**comment_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_profile"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_profile"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryAqua50"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="5" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_one"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_thumb_up_grey"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_thumb_up_grey" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_thumb_up_red"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_thumb_up_red"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comment_likes_number"
            android:layout_width="16sp"
            android:layout_height="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_thumb_down_grey"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_thumb_down_grey" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_thumb_down_black"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_thumb_down_black"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comment_dislikes_number"
            android:layout_width="16sp"
            android:layout_height="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_comment_grey"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_comment_grey" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_comment_blue"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_comment_blue"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comment_response_number"
            android:layout_width="16sp"
            android:layout_height="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**CommentAdapter**

```
       holder.commentLike.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        if (holder.commentLike.getTag().equals("like")) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Likes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Likes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        });

        holder.commentDislike.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            if (holder.commentDislike.getTag().equals("dislike")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Dislikes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Don't be mean", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Dislikes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        });


    private void commentLike(final String commentid, final ImageView imageView) {
            if (commentid != null) {


   DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(commentid).child("Likes");
            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (mFirebaseUser != null)
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).exists()) {
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_red);
                            imageView.setTag("liked");
                        } else {
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_grey);
                            imageView.setTag("like");
                        }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void commentDislike(final String commentid, final ImageView imageView) {
        if (commentid != null) {
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(commentid).child("Dislikes");
            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (mFirebaseUser != null)
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).exists()) {
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_down_black);
                            imageView.setTag("disliked");
                        } else {
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_down_grey);
                            imageView.setTag("dislike");
                        }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void commentLikesNumber(TextView commentLikesNumber, String commentid) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(commentid).child("Likes");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                commentLikesNumber.setText(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void commentDislikesNumber(TextView commentDislikesNumber, String commentid) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(commentid).child("Dislikes");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                commentDislikesNumber.setText(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you notifyDatasetChanged() of your adapter for each hit of like/dislike button , that causes to updated all the images of all comment rows.
So first thing, get rid of the `notifyDatasetChanged()` in the below listener

```
    holder.commentLike.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        if (holder.commentLike.getTag().equals("like")) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments Liked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
        } else {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments Liked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    });

    holder.commentDislike.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        if (holder.commentDislike.getTag().equals("dislike")) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Don't be mean", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    });
```

Second point, you set a boolean in firebase to true when you hit the like button and to false for dislike button.

You can manipulate the `datasnapshot` as a Boolean in your adapter by casting that to Boolean and if it's true then you can set the image to the red as "like" and to "gray" otherwise.

```
 private void commentLike(final String commentid, final ImageView imageView) {
    if (commentid != null) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments Liked").child(commentid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (mFirebaseUser != null)
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).exists()) {

                        boolean value = (Boolean) dataSnapshot.child((mFirebaseUser.getUid()).getValue();
                        if (value) {
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_red);
                            imageView.setTag("liked");

                        } else {
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_grey);
                            imageView.setTag("like");

                        }

                    } else {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_grey);
                        imageView.setTag("like");
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also do the same for the `commentDislike()` method.

Comment: I implemented this code, but the app crashed... It gave me a null pointer. I also tried it like this ```if (imageView.getTag()).equals("like")) { …```, but still crashed...

Comment: @JMB please let me check more

Comment: Okay man, thanks. Let me know if you see the problem... I tried this also, but not working either... ```if (dataSnapshot.child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).exists() && commentid.equals(mComment.get(position))) { …```

Comment: @JMB can you keep the part  of condition `if (dataSnapshot.child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).exists()) {`  , and remove the `else` part, and notice if the some images skip fiipping ? also you can test it the other way, so keep the `else` condition, and remove the other... I just want to make sure if the problem in this section or not

Comment: also notice if the images are removed totally or not

Comment: If I get rid of the second part, the else statement then this holder part of my code won't execute. I just uploaded it. Have a look at it in my **CommentAdapter**. I got rid of the else statement and it crashed because of the holder...

Comment: Do you think the problem I have in my xml file? Even the ImageProfile of user's in comments is blinking... I  think the problem might be there. What do you think? The Image Profile of the user blinks when  I click like or dislike... Maybe I have to do a constraint layout I don't know...

Comment: @JMB this is a good piece of information that makes the layout has a big chance of the issue .. let's examine it though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211759/discussion-between-zain-and-jmb).